# how to insert the elements in an XML file with QXmlStreamWriter

Tags: xml, qt

I created an xml file with QXmlStreamWriter, then I want to add in each time, some elements in the file before closing the xml document.

before posting on the forum I tried two methods:
1/

```
file.open(QFile:Append | QFile::Text);
QXmlStreamWriter xmlWriter(&file);
xmlWriter.setAutoFormatting(true);
xmlWriter.setAutoFormattingIndent(2);

xmlWriter.writeStartDocument();
xmlWriter.writeStartElement("Fiche_Du_Patient");
xmlWriter.writeStartElement("NUMERO_Patient");
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Num_Patient", ui.lineEdit_numPtient- >text().toAscii());
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Nom_et_prenom", ui.lineEdit_Nom->text().toAscii());
xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Date_de_naissance", ui.lineEdit_DOB->text().toAscii());
.......
xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
xmlWriter.writeEndDocument();
```

with this method, when I wanted to retrieve the values ​​of the xml file, the program accesses the first document values ​​ and displays an error : 
*xml declaration not at start of document*

the 2nd method : I remove writeStartDocument() and writeEndDocument() when adding, but I got this error:
*extra content at end of document*

the solution is added to the end before closing the document so that I can get different values

Can you help me please!!

Answer (score 2):

I think that only a dirty hack can avoid to read full XML to memory and rewrite:

```
 {
    QString path("/home/carlo/test/x.xml");
    QString ctag = "</Fiche_Du_Patient>\n";

    QFile file(path);
    qint64 s = file.size();
    if (s > 0) {
        file.open(QFile::ReadWrite);
        if (file.seek(s - ctag.length()))
            Q_ASSERT(file.pos() == s - ctag.length());

    } else
        file.open(QFile::WriteOnly);

    QXmlStreamWriter xmlWriter(&file);
    xmlWriter.setAutoFormatting(true);
    xmlWriter.setAutoFormattingIndent(2);

    if (s == 0) {
        xmlWriter.writeStartDocument();
        xmlWriter.writeStartElement("Fiche_Du_Patient");
    }

    xmlWriter.writeStartElement("NUMERO_Patient");
    xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Num_Patient", "123");
    xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Nom_et_prenom", s > 0 ? "appending" : "creating");
    xmlWriter.writeTextElement("Date_de_naissance", s > 0 ? "more date" : "first date");
    xmlWriter.writeEndElement();

    if (s == 0) {
        xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
        xmlWriter.writeEndDocument();
    }
    else
        QTextStream(&file) << ctag;
}
```

this seems to produce correct XML, but the format output isn't optimal (the nice indentation is lost). A better way would parse the last tag, without hard coding it.

HTH

Comment: could you tell me what is the real problem. would it cause any problem if I need to parse the output?